# Activating and deactivating a lodestone trap

Tags: pathfinder-1e, new-gm, traps

I'm a fairly new GM and in the process of working through a campaign I came across a lodestone trap that is activated when a pressure plate has more than 30 pounds placed on it, which sends out a electrical discharge that activates the trap. It says that the trap can be deactivated by another electric charge so I was wondering if a player steps on another pressure plate would that deactivate the trap. And if so would them constantly stepping on the plates turn it on and off again or would the first time be enough to turn it off completely?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are looking at the complicated trap described [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps/lodestone-trap-cr-2/). The transcript is pretty long, so I'll avoid quoting the whole thing and rely on excerpts.

First things first: this is a complicated trap that was made specifically for use with a custom chamber/terrain. You can find its details in the Pathfinder Module "D1: Crown of the Kobold King". This original source will likely have some additional detail that may help you understand the trap better.

So, based on how I'm parsing the description, the trap consists of two main elements. First, every time someone steps on one of many pressure plates, they get zapped for 1d6 electrical damage.

> Anyone stepping on a pressure plate unleashes a magical discharge of energy and takes 1d6 electricity damage.

Second, whenever they step on a pressure plate they also toggle the magnetic properties of the obelisk. The full description for how the magnetic pull works is in the link above.

> This charge also activates the powerful magnetic quality of the obelisk.

We also have information about how long the obelisk magnetic pull lasts.

> The lodestone retains its magnetic quality for 1d4 minutes [...]

And finally the text clarifies that the magnets can be turned off early, but only if you trigger another plate and get another zap to happen.

> [...] but can be deactivated earlier if it is struck with a second electrical discharge.

So a player stepping on a plate shocks them and activates the obelisk. The second action of stepping on a plate delivers a shock and deactivates the obelisk. Stepping on a 3rd plate will deliver a shock and reactivate the obelisk. And so on. We know that plates 3+ continue to toggle the trap because of the trap's reset type:

> **Reset** automatic

Since there is no special text for deactivating the trap as a whole, you can either bypass it by following the "safe path" given in the description, or by using the Disable Device skill to defuse the trap.

Answer (score 1):

### Once the trap is disabled, all plates are safe

The description of the [Lodestone Trap](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps/lodestone-trap-cr-2/) is of an entire room filled with pressure plates that activate the trap. Which means that once found and disabled, the trap stops working completely. It's reset is no longer triggered and the room is now safe to walk around.

> Anyone stepping on a pressure plate unleashes a magical discharge of energy and takes 1d6 electricity damage.

If the trap is not disabled, stepping on pressure plates will simply discharge another eletrical jolt. So if they walk around the room and step on five plates, they will take five different discharges of 1d6 each, as the trap resets immediatelly after being triggered.

[That room](http://paizo.com/products/btpy7yqz?GameMastery-Module-D1-Crown-of-the-Kobold-King) is a *deathtrap*. It's CR is unbalanced because it was designed for 3.5, not pathfinder. If you look at the trap designing rules, you will get: Perception DC 21 (+1 CR), Disable Device DC 21 (+1 CR), automatic reset (+1 CR), never miss (CR +2), 1st level spell (+1 CR). Total of CR 6. Of course this value can be tweaked because the damage on the trap is low (average 3), but it is still a TPK waiting to happen if the group lacks a trapfinder.